# Couldn't see the output of julia in atom

Tags: python, julia, atom-editor

I am currently learning julia programming language and Installed atom's juno as my code editor but when I clicked on the run all button neither if showed any error nor executed the code. Further I visited many websites but couldn't get answer. Please tell how to fix this problem? I am using julia 1.5.1

Comment: share screen shot of your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using atom then first start the julia by pressing Ctrl+Enter, once julia loads then run your code by pressing Ctrl+Enter.

Note: you can see your output in REPL window.

Comment: I know this but when Julia starts it shows directory error and when I try to execute a code it doesn't start

Comment: then try to execute code in Jupiter notebook

Comment: you can execute julia code in Jupiter also.

Comment: How can I do that pls explain

Comment: I have added the explanation in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about running Julia in Atom. However, it can be run in Jupyter notebooks. The procedure is as follows:

Open the Julia prompt/CLI and use the following code to add the IJulia package:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

Kill all existing Jupyter sessions and restart them. Now there must be an option to start a Julia session.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to debug this given the limited amount of information you've provided - I understand that you are using Julia 1.5.1 and are seeing a "directory error" when running code in Juno/Atom.

Firstly, contrary to one of the answers below, it is definitely possible to run Julia in Atom - the Julia client is called `Juno` (documentation [here](http://docs.junolab.org)).

Secondly, you are not on the latest Julia release - I don't think this affects anything here, but it's usually good practice to use the latest stable version, which is currently 1.5.3. I would therefore recommend that you

1. Download and install the latest stable Julia release, 1.5.3
2. Follow the [Juno installation instructions](http://docs.junolab.org/stable/man/installation/) in the docs step-by-step

If after this you run into problems, please edit your question and add whatever error messages you are seeing.

Given your comment about a "directory error" you might just not have the correct path set for your Julia installation - in Atom, go to Settings > Packages > julia-client > Settings and check the path of your Julia executable:

[image]

I should also note that while Juno is still actively maintained and expected to work error-free with the latest Julia release, it is not being actively developed anymore so you won't see new features. Development focus has shifted to VSCode, which offers a Julia plugin that offers almost all of the same features as Juno (and some features that Juno doesn't have) and is arguably somewhat easier to install. You can find more info on https://www.julia-vscode.org/